# Erro ao tentar obter evento de um caixa compartilhada utilizando o Graph

Tags: api, email, microsoft-azure, graphql

Atualmente, tenho um fluxo no power automate que lê uma lista do sharepont. Para cada nova linha ele dispara o email, cuja ação é ("Enviar email").

Nesse momento, tenho a necessidade de ao invés de mandar email, ele mande um invite do calendário de uma caixa compartilhada.

Aconte que montei o fluxo, utilizando a ação ("Enviar uma solicitação HTTP") cuja os paramentros vou deixar mais abaixo. Utilizando meu email, e um ID da mensagem do meu email, funcionou perfeitamente. Ao mudar o ID da mensagem que foi criado na caixa de email generica (eu tenho acesso), ele não funciona, gerando erro abaixo:

Açao outlook que usei (Enviar solicitação HTTP)
uri: [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/{Aqui](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/%7BAqui) estou usando ID da mensagem}
metodo: PATCH
corpo: {"hideAttendees": true}
Tipo de conexao: application/json

---

Esperava que o fluxo atualizasse o evento com o email do novo participante.

---

Porém recebo o erro abaixo:
Erro gerado:
{
"error": {
"code": "ErrorInvalidRequest",
"message": "Your request can't be completed. This operation does not support binding to a non-calendar folder."
}
}

---

Algum amigo irmão consegue me ajudar com o erro, ou passando um caminho alternativo?
Desde já, meu muito obrigado!!!